# Change values of my elements back to zero (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

So in my code, I ask the user 3 things:

1. Adding a value to a certain array
2. Displaying the array
3. Clearing the array.

I can't seem to be able to clear the array. I want it so that my array grid changes all of its values back to zero. I've tried `Arrays.fill(MyGrid,null)` and `Arrays.fill(MyGrid,0)`.

Both don't set the values back to zero. Is there something I'm missing?

```
 while(choice != 4)
{
    try{
  System.out.println("\nPlease choice an option:"
            + "\n1. Add value into an array"
            + "\n2. Print Grid"
            + "\n3. Clear Grid"
            + "\n4. Quit");

  choice = Integer.parseInt(myScan.nextLine());

    if(choice == 1)
    {
         System.out.println("Enter a row to put data into:  ");
  xRow = Integer.parseInt(myScan.nextLine());
  System.out.println("Enter a column to put data into:  ");
  xCol = Integer.parseInt(myScan.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter desired value: ");

 userData = Integer.parseInt(myScan.nextLine());

  MySize[xRow][xCol] = userData; 

    }
    else if(choice == 2)
    {
        for(int rowcntr = 0; rowcntr < userRow; rowcntr++)
   {
       for(int colcntr = 0; colcntr < userCol; colcntr++)
       {
           System.out.print(MySize[rowcntr][colcntr] + " ");
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
    }
    else if(choice == 3)
    {
        Arrays.fill(MySize,0);

    }
```

so this is part of the code, its in a loop so each time i enter a new value i can display it.

Comment: What is the type of your array?

Comment: I used int for the array

Comment: show some code.

Comment: Do you guys see what the problem is? cause to me it seems like if i choose 3 i should be able to create all the values back to 0. Not make my grid disappear!

Answer (score 1):

Since your Array `MySize[][]` is two dimensional you can't use

```
Arrays.fill(MySize, 0);
```

because this method is defined for one dimensional Arrays. [See here!](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(int[],%20int))
Use

```
for(int[] row : MySize){
    Arrays.fill(row, 0);
}
```

instead. This will iterate over the one dimensional row Arrays that you can fill with the `Arrays.fill` method.

Answer (score 0):

I've run this code. It works fine:

```
public class ArrayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)); // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
        Arrays.fill(a, 0);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)); // prints [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }
}
```